# Run a job if the tag that is triggering it was created on master

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, tags

my configurations looks something like this:

```
java-prod-build:
    stage: build
    only:
        - tags
    before_script:
        - env
        - declare RELEASE_VERSION=$(echo "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" | sed 's/.*-//') && echo $RELEASE_VERSION
        - echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA && echo $CI_JOB_STARTED_AT
script:
        - ...
```

I would love to run that script only if the tag was created on a commit that "belongs" to the master branch.

Unfortunately scanning through the variables reveals that the typical fields now contain the tag name:

CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=rpk-10.9.117,
CI_BUILD_REF_NAME=rpk-10.9.117

Is there an easy way of doing it?

I am pretty new to GitLab-CI stuff and reading the documentation I can't find anything specific enough to help me out :/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You would do something like this (sorry for the poor formatting, but you get the idea):

```
only:
    refs:
      - my-branch
tags:
    - my-tag
```

---

A better way than "only", which is not [actively developed](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except), would be to use [rules:if](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif).

You can also check the [CI/CD env variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) to help you achieve your goal.

Not tested, but it could look something like this:

```
job:
  script: my_script
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG == my-commit-tag && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == master'
```

I'll let you fiddle with variables and `if` rules to suit your needs

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can you clarify what "my-tag" would look like?

Comment: Ah, I thought you were talking about runners with the "tag" thing. I'll update my answer

Comment: It might just be that I am not able to understand correctly but there is no $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH when pushing a tag right!?

Comment: You don't *push or commit* a tag, you push/commit **sources**. A tag is just a pointer to a specific moment in your git history. When you create a tag, you specify a commit (or you don't, and the last commit on your current branch will be taken), which is unrelated to branches. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27154277/5467710) for more info on tags and branches. The `if` condition in my answer is just a way to say: `if the tag is my-commit-tag and the branch is master, run the job`. You can also fiddle with the `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` CI/CD var

Comment: Well in Fork I create a tag by rightcklicking a commit and selecting "create tag" (giving it a name here) wich is then listed under Tags. I then rightclick that tag and click on push Tag to origin. Which is exactly the point I would want the script to run. But as I just mentioned there is no $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH (it is empty)

Comment: the answer don't work as tags don't belong to a commit. when pushing a tag, CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is empty