# GitHub actions tag

Tags: github-actions

I'm currently trying to allow tags only on the main branch. But I can't seem to get it to work. This is what I currently have but it also triggers the production build if a tag is being put on a develop/release/hotfix branch.. Is there a way to check if the tag has been created on the main branch?

Current YAML:

```yaml
name: Release to production
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'hotfix/**'
    tags:
      - 'v*'
    
jobs:
  get-version-data:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get production version from tag
        if: ${{ startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/v') }}
        id: get_version
        run: echo "VERSION=$(echo ${{ github.ref }} | cut -d '/' -f 3 | cut -c2-)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Get hotfix version from tag
        if: ${{ contains(github.ref, 'hotfix') }}
        id: split
        uses: jungwinter/split@v2
        with:
          separator: '/'
          msg: ${{ github.ref }}
      
      - name: Write hotfix version to env
        if: ${{ contains(github.ref, 'hotfix') }}
        run: echo "VERSION=${{ steps.split.outputs._3 }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Exit if version could not be determined
        if: ${{ env.VERSION == '' }}
        run: exit -1

      - name: Build Number
        run: echo "BUILD_NUMBER=$(($GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER + 125))" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    outputs:
      version: ${{ env.VERSION }}
      build-number: ${{ env.BUILD_NUMBER }}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do Git tags only apply to the current branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613540/do-git-tags-only-apply-to-the-current-branch)