# How to run a Gitlab-CI job only if a tag is created on the main branch

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a job to create a release when a tag is created but I also need a rule to only allow it to create a release if the tag was created for the main branch. I'm not sure what I need to do for this?

I've tried this rule however this fails in the pipeline because this command stops it from running for some reason.

```
  rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  script:
```

Comment: Your rule is failing probably because CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is only available in branch pipeline, not tag pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78202211/21159306) for their answer which led me in the right direction for sure. The best result I've gotten is with this snippet.

```
Script:
- git log -1 --pretty='%D' $CI_COMMIT_TAG > tag_info.txt
- | 
    if ! grep -q 'origin/master' tag_info.txt; then
      exit 1
    fi
```

This sends the information from the tag I just created to a text file and grep checks if the text file contains the branch I want, if it doesn't the pipeline fails otherwise I can carry on with my release.

Answer (score 0):

You have a misunderstanding on how tags work. Please read though [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27154277/6845813) for full explanation, but here's a snippet from it:

> It is important to understand that tags have no direct relationship with branches - they only ever identify a commit.

So, when a tag is created, even for a branch, it is not really created *for* that branch, but as a reference to the latest *commit* in that branch. That is also why [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) mentions these:

- `CI_COMMIT_TAG` - The commit tag name. Available only in pipelines for tags.
- `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` - The commit branch name. Available in branch pipelines, including pipelines for the default branch. Not available in merge request pipelines or tag pipelines.

So, your pipeline will fail because those two variables can't coexist, so your question becomes a bit problematic.

Maybe you wan't to identify if the commit of the tag is available in the main branch? In theory something like this could help: [Git: How to find out on which branch a tag is?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15806668/6845813), but you cannot run arbitrary git operations in a GitLab `rules:if` clause.

Not ideal, but your best option is probably to do the check in a script and fail the job in case the tag was not created for a commit that exists in the main branch:

```
  script:
    - | 
        if [[ -z $(git branch --list $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH --contains tags/$CI_COMMIT_TAG) ]]; then
           exit 1
        fi
```